# How to invoke an API Gateway endpoint with IAM_AUTH without cognito

Tags: typescript, http, axios, aws-api-gateway

I have an endpoint on API gateway I want to callout to protected with `IAM_AUTH`. I am using [aws-4axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws4-axios) to generate the AWSv4 signature.

```
export default class API {
  stage = (process.env.REACT_APP_STAGE || 'dev').toUpperCase();
  client: AxiosInstance;

  constructor(accessKey: string, secretKey: string) {
    const interceptor = aws4Interceptor(
      {
        region: 'us-east-1',
        service: 'execute-api',
      },
      {
        accessKeyId: accessKey,
        secretAccessKey: secretKey,
      },
    );
    this.client = axios.create();
    this.client.interceptors.request.use(interceptor);
  }

  public async createSetupIntent(customer_id: string): Promise<void> {
    const response = await this.client.post(
      `${process.env[`REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT_${this.stage}`]}/${CREATE_SETUP_INTENT_ENDPOINT}`,
      JSON.stringify({ customer_id }),
    );
    console.log(response);
  }
}
```

The problem I'm having is I'm doing this client side in the browser and chrome throws an error setting the Host header which API Gateway [requires](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/api-reference/making-http-requests/), which in turn causes API Gateway to return a 403 response.

> Refused to set unsafe header "Host"

I'm guessing this is by design to prevent exactly what I'm trying to do - using the access/secret keys client side.

The reason I am doing this from the client side instead of server side and without cognito is because eventually these requests will be done on the server. This is simply just a dummy/proof of concept/ temporary solution to use while developing other aspects of the application until we integrate with other servers.

Is it possible to callout to an `IAM_AUTH` endpoint from a browser without cognito?

Answer (score 1):

You do need to send a host header, but the browser actually does this for you - it automatically sets the host header to match the hostname in the URL, which is probably what you want (and that seems to be all that `aws4-axios` is doing in [its implementation](https://github.com/jamesmbourne/aws4-axios/blob/5a325482c811cfc5b21f11e2dcb1995f300defd0/src/interceptor.ts#L96) anyway).

The browser is just complaining because you're trying to override that, but you don't need to, you're really just using the default value.

The problem described here doesn't seem to be due to the IAM API, it looks like it's just an issue with `aws4-axios`, which is only designed to work in node (it uses [aws4](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws4) internally, which is explicitly node only).

I would suggest you drop that, and build the request yourself, by tweaking [their code](https://github.com/jamesmbourne/aws4-axios/blob/main/src/interceptor.ts#L115-L129), to calculate the same signature, but then just set the `Authorization` and maybe `x-amz-date` headers that are required, instead of trying to reset everything.

Alternatively, you might be interested in [aws4fetch](https://github.com/mhart/aws4fetch) which can do this all for you in the browser, but only for Fetch, not Axios.